# Diophantine System Solution

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Could you please help with finding of general solution of diophantine system for rational a, b, c, d

$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=A^2$

$(a^2-b^2)(c^2-d^2)=B^2$

for some rational A and B.

This is related to Ozanam's problem.

Comment: So are the $A,B$ considered as *given* and one looks for $a,b,c,d,$ is that what is meant?

Comment: @coffeemath: I don't think $A,B$ are given. I believe he just wants those two simultaneous expressions in $a,b,c,d$ to be made squares.

Comment: @TitoPiezas Yes I see the idea, I've encountered other problems where two polynomial expressions are to be simultaneously made squares, where it is irrelevant what squares.